# Different request for different data from API in the same page, React (No Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

To fetch different data from API should I use different request or one single fetch changing the variable?.
I have looked through internet and the answer/suggestion are almost all towards to PHP and I do not know this language really well. Therefore I am here to ask for suggestion/answer.

This is my code so far:

```
//fetching movie
  fetchMovie = (name) =>{
    const API = '&api_key=72049b7019c79f226fad8eec6e1ee889';
    let movieAPI = '';

    //if the length of the movies is equal to zero fetch default search
    if( this.state.movies.length === 0 ){
      movieAPI = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=72049b7019c79f226fad8eec6e1ee889&sort_by=popularity.desc&page=1";
    }else{
      //search the movie name
      movieAPI = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?page=1&query=" + name + API;
    }


    //make request
    const req = new Request(movieAPI, {
      method: 'GET',
      cache: 'default'
    });

    fetch(req).then(response =>{
      return response.json();
    }).then(data =>{
      //if data fetched result is greater than 0
      if(data.results.length > 0){
        this.setState({
          movies: data.results
        });
      }

    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("ERROR: " + err);
    })
  }
```

Now to explain what I want to understand is: 
As you can see from the code above I can only do a default request data or by name. Now if I want to fetch different query should I write a different code each of the query or reuse the code making so:

```
movieAPI = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/"+ variable +"/movie?api_key=72049b7019c79f226fad8eec6e1ee889&date="+ date +"&name=" +name + "&otherQuery=" + query ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what your app will do with these data.

I suggest you to create multiple functions for each type of data your app will fetch like these :

```
function fetchMovieByName(name){ ... }
function fetchMovieListByDate(beginDate, endDate, sort, page){ ... }
function fetchPopularMovieList(sort, page){ ... }
function fetchTopRatedMovieList(sort, page){ ... }
```

It'll be cleaner and easier to understand your code.

In case you want to do less requests you can fetch a list then store it and work on it client side to search/filter etc...